# AWS Lambda@Edge append querystring to response

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

Short Overview.

I host an Angular Application on an S3 Bucket. I also got an Cloudfront distribution to handle HTTPS and Redirects.

I try to form an querystring parameter depending on which URL the user is connecting to.

2 examples

```
test.example.com --> example.com?id=test
hello.example.com --> example.com?id?hello
```

So far i tried to implement an **AWS lambda@Edge Function** but nothing worked so far. If i try to manipulate the `request` it wont have any effects, if i try to manipulate the `response` the redirect does not work and i get an S3 bucket error or Cloudfront error.

```
'use strict';
const remove_suffix = '.example.com';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;
    const host_header = headers.host[0].value;

    if(host_header.endsWith(remove_suffix)){
        request.querystring = 'id=' + host_header.substring(0,host_header.length - remove_suffix.length);
    }

    return callback(null,request);
};
```

1) Which trigger should I use?

2) Which settings could I be missing on Cloudfront settings?

3) Is my Lambda function wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to ensure, that in the Cloudfront distribution `Behavior` settings, option `Query String Forwarding and Caching` is **not** set to `None (Improves Caching)`

You can find more info regarding that option in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesQueryString).

Comment: thx for the advice. I get the folliwing error `502 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
The Lambda function result failed validation: The function tried to add, delete, or change a read-only header. ` You mind to help me with this one?

Comment: Were there any changes in the code posted in the question? As I can see the original headers object is not modified there. And according to the examples in the documentation it is perfectly valid to overwrite `request.querystring`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-query-string-examples

Comment: The code i posted is still the same. Im currently using the `Viewer Response` Trigger.

Comment: Okay, I would try to change the trigger to `Viewer Request` to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Now i get redirected to the s3 bucket but without any querystrings which i can access

Comment: Wow, that was easy! Thanks!